# Ubuntu not working properly on the new Lenovo X1 Carbon

Tags: wireless, suspend, lenovo, bug-reporting, compatibility

I've recently changed my lenovo thinkpad X1 carbon gen1 (it broke :S). But since I liked it so much I changed it into the "new lenovo thinkpad X1 carbon" http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/x-series/x1-carbon/ .

I had ubuntu installed and working flawlessly on the old thinkpad, but once I tried to download it on my new laptop lots of bugs started occuring. Things like the wireless wasn't being recognized, not being able to boot back up after going to sleep etc...

I'm not really tech-savvy so I didn't really analyze the hardware when I bought it, but I assumed that hardware-wise, it wouldn't be much different. Does anybody here definitively know whether or not ubuntu is just not compatible with the new X1Carbon? Or did I do something wrong/miss something while installing?

Comment: The basic hardware components are definitively supported: http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201204-10913/. "Special" components like the adaptive keyboard are/will still ToDo or almost worked out.

Comment: See also: http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/detail.page?AliasID=linux-20A7004AJP and http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/detail.page?AliasID=linux-20A8Z05RUS.